# No logro modificar un items en mercadolibre con php

Tags: php, api, mercadolibre

Tengo este codigo el cual en teoría me permite modificar el stock de un item. Lo lee, no da error, pero no lo modifica.

```
<?php 
  $ACCESS_TOKEN="APP_USR-3743017...";
  $uso=1;
  $detallesART = '{"available_quantity":99}';
  $ITEM_ID="MLA663524414";
  $url="https://api.mercadolibre.com/items/$ITEM_ID?access_token=$ACCESS_TOKEN";
  $ch = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_GET, 1);
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_GETFIELDS, $detallesART);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
  $respuesta=curl_exec($ch);
  echo "<br>OK:".$respuesta;
  $error = curl_error($ch);
  echo "<br>Error:".$error;
  curl_close ($ch);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pienso que `CURLOPT_GET` deba `CURLOPT_POST`, y `CURLOPT_GETFIELDS` deba `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` porque `CURLOPT_GET` y `CURLOPT_GETFIELDS` no son opciones para `curl_setopt`. Mire a la documentación en php.net: http://php.net/manual/es/function.curl-setopt.php